# Is there a method for getting the state object data of history.pushState()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I change the browser's history in this way:

```
var state = { itemId: id };
history.pushState(state, null, someURL);
```

I can have lots of states(I think the maximum in Chrome is 50). Now, I want to get all my states, is there a method for that?

Something like: `history.getState()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design you can't read from the browser history, particularly since people reuse browser tabs all the time - you wouldn't want your browsing history in that tab available to any future site you happen to access, it would be a big, gaping privacy risk.

Comment: Thanks, sound logical. )))